# Вывод определенной части массива

Tags: java

Привет,возникла проблемка. Вот у нас есть массив:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Он содержит много элементов,а как из него вытащить десять элементов?первых?
Заранее,за примеры кода спасибо))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list.subList(0, 10)
```

Comment: Спасибо,а еще варианты есть?

Comment: @ваняя выбирать элементы в цикле по одному

Answer (score 5):

Такой вариант не подходит? :)

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   String el = list.get(i);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i=0; i<(list.size() < 10?list.size():10); i++)
   String el = list.get(i);
```

Comment: Ну тогда уж i < Math.min(10, list.size())

Comment: На фига подключать `Math`?

Comment: Хочет более "изящное"))решение

Comment: Да!ДА!ДААА!! Только подключение тяжелых классов! Только хардкор! Пять либ апача мне в глотку! (Прошу прощения, не сдержался...)

Comment: @Евгений Карпов: ну ладно уж вам. Мне кажется, использование `Math.min` в данном контексте делает код чище и понятнее. Хотя, конечно, у каждого свои предпочтения.

Comment: Дело в том, что привыкая к такому, с позволения сказать, расточительству, программист перестает осознавать, что такой код замедляет работу программы, а самое плохое - что я встречаю такие неоптимизованности в критичных местах кода, где каждый такт важен.

PS: В таком исполнении условие очень легко переносится в Асм. Переход же по классам, с учетом специфики Math - довольно затратное эстетическое удовольствие.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов 

Во-первых, Math.min содержит точно такую-же реализацию. Так что использование данного метода - хороший тон и следование принципу DRY. 

Во-вторых, метод min статический и его вызов будет заинлайнен компилятором. Из этого следует, что никаким расточительством здесь даже и не пахнет.

В-третьих, класс Math содержится в пакете java.lang, который импортирован по умолчанию. Это к слову о "пять либ апача в глотку" и о тяжелых классах.


Итого: у меня 3 аргумента за использование этого метода, и ни одного против. Что имеете возразить?

Comment: @Barmaley Что значить подключать? Этот класс определен в пакете java.lang.

Comment: @a_gura а возразить-то мне и нечего. Мне следует более глубоко изучать джаву. Только, хотелось бы подобного объяснения Вашего первого ответа, про саблист. Он же явно медленнее простого цикла?

Comment: @a_gura @Евгений Карпов - ИМХО спор ни о чем. Это напоминает битву [grammar nazi](http://lurkmore.to/Grammar_nazi)

Comment: @Евгений Карпов 

> Он же явно медленнее простого цикла?

уверены ?

Comment: @Евгений Карпов Автор вопроса спрашивал "как", а не "как быстрее" :)

Вообще subList создает новый экземпляр одного из подклассов AbstractList, который просто делегирует вызовы к оригинальному списку и дополнительно проверяет выход за границы указанного диапозона и возможную модификацию. Для получения n-первых (и вообще n-любых) элементов это достаточно эффективное решение. Для дальнейших рассуждений важно что именно с этими элементами предполагается делать и какой именно реализацией является оригинальный список.